# Changing value for non-valid key without using an if Statement

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my task:

Write a function get_value(dictionary, key) which returns the value for the given key in the given dictionary, using the get method. If the key is not valid, your function should return -1.

I have written a function which assesses a dictionary using a get function and the code work just fine. However, I need a way to return a value of -1 of the key is not valid instead of returning "Not a Key". I have been requested to solve this issue without the use of an if statement. Here is my current code:

```
def get_value(dictionary, key):
    for key in key.split("."):
        dictionary.get(key)
        dictionary = dictionary[key]
    return dictionary
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `dictionary = dictionary.get(key, -1)`?

Comment: It would help to add some context like example input and desired output.